# Ember.js: "autoinit: false" is not working anymore

Tags: initialization, ember.js, curl.js

I'm loading my whole application in parts, so somewhere at the beginning during this init process I create my app

```
window.Sp = Em.Application.create( {
    VERSION: '1.0.0',
    autoinit: false
}) ;
```

Then I start loading other things, like router settings. And when this is ready I called initialize

```
Sp.initialize() ;
```

This worked fine, until I donwloaded the most recent ember.js from https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js

It turned out that 'autoinit' as a configuration option is removed. Why? But more importantly what do I have to do if I want to call 'initialize' manually ?

I already found one way to hack around this, is to set **isDestroyed** to true, and just before calling initialize() set it to false :)

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L32, here for an example: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L364

Comment: I just tried your solution, but calling Sp.deferReadiness() and later Sp.advanceReadiness() only seem to influence when Sp.ready is called, not the initialize, which is still immediately called :( Unfortunately there is no such thing as a deferInitialize function

Comment: I think you don't have to call initialize() anymore. What I've seen by quicly reading the code, is that you call defereReadiness() after creating the app, do what you need before application initialize, and when you are ready, call advanceReadiness(). If it's not working, could you provide a little more context in your question, to see what you want to do before application is initialized ?

Comment: just found a doable solution. First I create a fake application like: Sp = { Router: Ember.Router.extend() }. Then Everything initializes and finally I do: Sp = Ember.Application.create(Sp) ; Give me some time then I'll upload it to github!

Comment: your solution is very weird from what I've seen since few month using ember. But yes, I will be pleased to take a look at your project :)

Comment: I've just committed everything. The index.html file is located  here: http://bit.ly/VRV4t1

Comment: Probably there is something going wrong with curl.js AMD loading... but here, I'm so sorry, I can't help you more :s, I don't know how all this is supposed to work :(

Comment: the reason I use curl is I could easily load the template files, instead of defining them in the <body>.

Comment: I am not sure if something changed with the pre3 and pre4 releases, but I am using deferReadiness and advanceReadiness in my application and it is not calling initialize until I advance.  I am also using AMD, require.js specifically.  My application is designed quite a bit differently however.  I load all my resources in bundles with AMD and then run advanceReadiness.

Comment: Hey Jeanluca, I can't help much with ember, but I noticed your use of curl.js is pretty inefficient.  You should consider taking each of the module lists and placing them into one or more "run" modules (aka "main" modules by RequireJS) and bundling them with cram.js.  Also, if you can load these run modules in parallel (rather than use curl().then() or curl().next()), that would be even better.  You can get more help with curl.js and cram.js over at https://groups.google.com/d/forum/cujojs :)